# Hydrogen Remix PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large

Tags: shopify, remix, storefront, hydrogen

I send a form `Form encType="multipart/form-data"`. If the file size exceeds 100kb I get an error. Is there any way to increase this limit?

[image]

I use Shopify Hydrogen. Remix

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.